# Agreement between two sets of data on partitions

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, partitions

Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dotsc,\lambda_{\ell(\lambda)})$ be an integer partition of positive numbers where $\ell(\lambda)$ is the *length* of the partition. One may associate a *Ferrer diagram* or *Young diagram* $Y$ to $\lambda$. I read this concept *Ferrer's matrix* on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A237981) but nowhere else.

First, compute $m=\max\{\lambda_1,\ell(\lambda)\}$ and then construct an $m\times m$ matrix by inserting a $1$ in each box of $Y$ while inserting $0$ elsewhere. For example, if $\lambda=(4,3,1)\vdash 8$ then $m=4$ and the corresponding matrix becomes
$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&1 \\ 1&1&1&0 \\ 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$.
Now, add elements of all anti-diagonals to get $(1,2,3,2,0,0,0)$. Re-sorting (and ignoring $0$'s) gives $\mu=(3,2,2,1)\vdash 8$.

If one does apply the procedure to all (ordered) partitions of $n=4$, i.e. $\{4, 31, 22, 211, 1111\}$, the resulting partitions form the multi-set $\{1111, 211, 211, 211, 1111\}$. The new statistic (frequencies) reads $2, 3$. Here is a short table from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A238325):
$$\begin{array}l
1 \\ 2 \\ 2, 1 \\ 2, 3 \\ 2, 2, 3 \\ 2, 2, 6, 1 \\ 2, 2, 4, 3, 4.
\end{array}$$
On a different route, given any partition $\lambda$ of $n$, compute its [hook-lengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) and add them to generate some statistic. As an example, take $n=4$. Associate the set hook-lengths
$\{(4, 3, 2, 1), (4, 1, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2, 1), (4, 2, 1, 1), (4, 3, 2, 1)\}$. The resulting multi-set
of sums is $\{10, 8, 8, 8, 10\}$ with frequencies $2, 3$.

> **QUESTION.** Is there a bijection to explain the total agreement between the two statistics (see above table)? I would also be nice if there is a generating function here.

**REMARK.** The sum of hooks of $\lambda$ equals sum of squares of parts of $\lambda$.

**UPDATE.** Peter Taylor (comments below [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420033/agreement-between-two-sets-of-data-on-partitions#comment1078838_420033) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420033/agreement-between-two-sets-of-data-on-partitions#comment1078846_420033)) identified an error in the above correspondence. So, the answer to my question is **negative**, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you saying you know that for all values of $n$ these two statistics have the same frequencies on partitions of $n$?

Comment: @SamHopkins: I was able to compute the latter data and it agrees with the one shown. Is that what you ask?

Comment: it might make sense to ask findstat, but I can probably only do so on monday.

Comment: How far did you compute it? I don't think that it agrees for $n=9$ (although a less strong agreement seems to hold: the issue is that both $(1, 2, 2, 2, 2)$ and $(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3)$ correspond to hook length sum $29$).

Comment: The table for row $9$ on OEIS seems wrong: it does not add up to $30$, the number of partitions $p(9)$. They had it as $27$. What do you think?

Comment: I didn't look at OEIS, just computed it from scratch in Sage. [Online workbook](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1UcuOgjAU3ZvwDzeuinaMzHIyzmZ-wLiUGINyceq0t1hKZP5-KEUBUZbnHM7jNjNawVFLiUcrNBUgVK6NhW9dkkUTTILJZvF54fYLVrDW8o-0EoncCDqx7TZ0fIoZqJJJdUiT8COYQP1RrS5K1YIeS0VyKmo8Xu5gBux9Ri2RaQOCwxUEAVKp0CQWh3432dlpTEInZNc-d_ePxVsEczjvYL6CyAsM2tIQFPUuTFnVGFXOyDcSGVTNEIdTFxBxiJa3ECfdZwYvbkF7HNb2_9H6d1-vfcUftToIwvQV73KbtS57nRgrmqdg1F-YG0HWH4V79cLlFizk3fXDTt8Vjm2ZS2SdqH-bcf_4_m63gNEPw0ExewzgMPYYmPgxU4Ap7xUNx-Sw2hPBsMoTgURivQgPPNh68MFq4BX-A6eY7fg=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I now understand what you mentioned. You are right, unfortunately. Thank you, indeed.

Comment: The dynamics of the map $\lambda \mapsto \mu$ might still be interesting to explore further.

Comment: @SamHopkins, it turns out to be idempotent.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan it might be good to edit the OEIS

Answer (score 3):

> First, compute $m=\max\{\lambda_1,\ell(\lambda)\}$ and then construct an $m\times m$ matrix by inserting a $1$ in each box of $Y$ while inserting $0$ elsewhere. For example, if $\lambda=(4,3,1)\vdash 8$ then $m=4$ and the corresponding matrix becomes
> $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&1 \\ 1&1&1&0 \\ 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0
> \end{pmatrix}$.
> Now, add elements of all anti-diagonals to get $(1,2,3,2,0,0,0)$. Re-sorting (and ignoring $0$'s) gives $\mu=(3,2,2,1)\vdash 8$.

The sorting is a bit of a red herring. Denote the anti-diagonal frequency vector, $(1,2,3,2,0,0,0)$ in the example, as $(ad_1, ad_2, ad_3, \ldots)$. It's easy to see that $ad_k > ad_{k-1}$ requires $\forall 1 \le i \le k: ad_i = i$. So if $A = \max(\mu)$ the unique "unsorting" to a legal anti-diagonal frequency vector which produces it is $(1, 2, 3, \ldots, A, ad_{A+1}, ad_{A+2}, \ldots)$ with $A \ge ad_{A+1} \ge ad_{A+2} \ge \cdots$

Let $H$ denote the hook length sum. Suppose we build the Ferrers diagram starting from the unique partition of $1$ and adding a cell at a time in such a way that we always have a valid Ferrers diagram. When we add a cell at $(r, c)$ we increase $ad_{r+c-1}$ by $1$ and $H$ by $(r-1)+(c-1)+1 = r+c-1$, so $H - \sum_k k \cdot ad_k$ is invariant. The initial partition has $H=1$, $ad_1 = 1$, so $$H = \sum_k k \cdot ad_k$$

Thus for every $\mu$ there is a unique hook length sum $H_{\mu}$ which all partitions having that anti-diagonal frequency partition share, but there's nothing to prevent different $\mu$ sharing their hook length sum, and e.g. anti-diagonal frequency vectors $(1,2,2,2,2) \to 1 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 = 29$ and $(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1) \to 1 + 4 + 9 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 29$ collide.

Comment: The number of distinct $\mu$ among partitions of $n$ is [A000009](https://oeis.org/A000009): see Jon Perry's comment of Sep 21 2005.